# super.init' cannot be called outside of an initializer in swift

Tags: swift, ios8

```
code:
     override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
                super.init(context: context)
                let date: NSDate? = DataAccess.sharedInstance.getLatestDate()
                if date != nil {
                    dateLabel.setText(date!.description)
                }
            }
```

i am using xcode6.3 beta. when i run project it give error as "super.init' cannot be called outside of an initializer" why i am getting this error.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specified init doesn't exist anymore. You have to use `super.awakeWithContext(context)` instead:

So replace:

```
super.init(context: context)
```

with:

```
super.awakeWithContext(context)
```